# Number of Hamilton paths in an extremely dense undirected simple graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

What is the fastest way (algorithm) to calculate the number of Hamilton paths in an extremely dense undirected simple graph (approximately 99.99% edges are connected)?

I was thinking of the following way :

First, calculate the number of Hamilton paths in the complete graph.

Remove one edge at a time, but I am not able to figure out how many paths would be reduced on removing an edge. Also how to prevent double counting while removing the edges ?

I came across a similar question on Math.SE but that was about Hamilton cycles and not paths, I hope that changes the question significantly. Also the answers were not quite clear, hence this post.

Comment: How large will your graphs be and how many edges will be removed? 1-2 or 100-200?

Comment: There can be upto 10^5 nodes and roughly <10 edges would be removed. How can I tackle this problem now ?

Comment: Is it possible that edges are adjacent? I think it would be easier if they were not.

Comment: Do you mean the removed edges ? If yes, the removed edges can be adjacent.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant the removed edges. Ok, I'll think about it. I think I will have to update my answer because there is certainly a way to do this faster but I can't just write it down in a concise way yet.

Comment: Anything yet ? I was wondering about inclusion exclusion principle with the removed edges. That is, consider how many paths can be made with removed edges and subtract them from (n!). The algorithm seems fine , got it working on some examples , but I do not know how to implement it. Are you thinking something similar ? @lex82

Comment: I updated my answer. Unfortunately there is no simple formula but I think generating the complementary paths (the ones not possible because some edges are missing) is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can calculate the number of Hamilton paths without
actually generating the paths or considering each path individually
when counting. For special graphs -- like the complete graph -- this
is certainly possible but not in general.

You could generate all Hamilton paths in the complete graph and check
for each one if it uses a subset of the edges in your graph. Of course
you can speed things up by already pruning certain branches while
generating the Hamilton paths in the complete graph.

Since your graph is very large, this approach is certainly not
feasible. However, you can calculate the number of all paths in the
complete graph that contain one of the missing edges and then subtract
this number.

I don't think this is trivial. Some thoughts on it: Let's consider the
simplest case that only one edge is missing. We can describe a path
with a sequence of edges or nodes. Let's say your graph has n
nodes. There are `n-1` possible positions of the missing edge in a
hamilton path through the complete graph. The edge may be traversed in
two directions and the nodes not adjacent to the edge can be traversed
in `(n-2)!` different orders. Hence we can subtract

```
2 * (n-1) * (n-2)! = 2 * (n-1)!
```

from the total number of hamilton paths through the complete graph to
obtain the desired result.

If exactly two edges are missing we cannot just subtract twice the
number because we are counting several paths twice, namely the paths
containing both edges. So we have to calculate this number and add it
again. But now it becomes complicated: It is important how the edges
are related. If they are adjacent, the number is smaller than it would
be otherwise. So in general you cannot just calculate the number of
hamilton paths containing `k` of of the missing edges but it is
important which edges you are considering and whether they are
adjacent or not.

But let's say you can calculate the number of paths through a certain
selection of edges (all permutations, directions of traversal and
positions in the paths). Let's further assume that `k` edges are
missing. You can calculate the number of paths including at least one
of the edges like this:

Calculate the number of paths through any of the `k` edges individually
and sum them up.

For each pair of edges you have counted the paths traversing the pair
twice, so subtract these paths again (consider each pair
individually).

Now consider the paths containing three of the edges. They have been
counted six times and subtracted three times (3 different pairs), so
you have to subtract them twice.

The paths containing four edges have to be subtracted 3 times (because
they are represented 4 times in the paths containing 3 edges). And so
on.

But again: You have to consider each combination of edges
individually. It is even possible that a certain set of edges is
incompatible because a certain node occurs three times. Also take into
account the directions in which the edges are traversed.

So there is no simple formula but if the number of missing edges is
really small, you can count the paths.

Comment: If I am not wrong, there are n! paths for a complete graph. Wouldn't that make it an O(n!) algorithm? How can I speed it up, please be more specific. Also what exactly do you mean by "special graphs" here ?

Comment: With special graphs I mean for instance the complete graph (updated the answer too). Yes, complexity would be O(n!). This only works for rather small graphs. I'll think about it. Maybe I find a better solution.